# In SCVMM, How do I fix Custom Property X violates a property matching rule for the value Y

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, powershell

I am trying to create a VM using System Center Virtual Machine Manager console. But I can't proceed with the VM creation because I get this error:

**The value for custom property 'Business Unit' specified by the host violates a property matching rule for the value '' specified by virtual machine 'test-vm'.**

[VM Create Error in VMM Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZhzl.png)

After I was getting this error, I deleted the custom property using powershell:

```
$cprop = Get-SCCustomProperty -Name "Business Unit" -VMMServer localhost;
Remove-SCCustomProperty -CustomProperty $cprop;
```

After that this custom property is not visible in the `Manage Custom Properties...` anymore, nor is it listed when I do `Get-SCCustomProperty -VMMServer localhost`.

[VM Host Custom Properties in VMM Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDkbm.png)

But I am still getting exactly the same error. It's strange because the specified custom property 'Business Unit' does not exist anymore.

I can't find it in Host Properties too.

```
> Get-SCVMHost -VMMServer localhost | Select CustomProperty

CustomProperty
--------------
{}
```

Can Custom Properties be defined in the host operating system itself? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Check if you have any existing placement rules. One is probably referencing your custom property. Likely also the same reason it wouldn't let you deploy the first time since it didn't like 'Business Unit' being null.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, there was a Placement rule which was referencing this Custom Property. After removing that rule, the error is gone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting a placement rule that was using this Custom Property, the error is gone.

An existing Placement rule using some Custom Property doesn't get removed if the  Custom Property itself gets deleted. VMM does not check this dependency when a Custom Property is deleted.

So, while deleting a custom property make sure you manually delete or edit the placement rules referencing the custom property, else can be stale dependencies.